# .net reflection assembly loading exception

Tags: .net, reflection

Hi i am loading an assembly as

```
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile("abc.dll");
Type t = testAssembly.GetType("abc.dll");
```

but getting an error "Absolute path information is required" however my dll is located in the same folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

wal has a good point about the `GetType` method call, but to answer the question:

```
string path = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "abc.dll");
Assembly testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
```

If `AppDomain.CurrentDomain` isn't reliable, then a slightly more convoluted way:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "abc.dll");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `Assembly.LoadFile` if your dll is a .NET dll and in the same folder. You can simply call

```
Type t = Type.GetType("SomeType");
```

Are you really trying to get the type 'abc.dll' ? This should be a class name, not an assembly name.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the DLL file from the specific path directly creates issues so either you have to provide the absolute path or you can just try `LoadFrom()`

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:/CodeDLL.dll");
Type t= assembly.GetType("YourNamespace.YourClass");
```